# Create a journey via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api

I'm trying to create a Single-Send Journey using the API.
I can not understand two things:

1. How do I set to which DE to send
2. How to set the schedule

My trigger object:

```
"triggers": [
    {
        "key": "event-key",
        "name": "Starting point for the journey",
        "eventDefinitionKey": "my-entry-event-key",
        "type": "EmailAudience",
        "arguments": {
            
        }
    }
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create an event definition following this article

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createEventDefinition.htm

You will get a response holding an eventDefinitionKey which can be used within the trigger object of the JSON for building your journey.

Regarding the scheduler, from my understanding when handling Journey's entirely from API you need to publish the journey manually following this article

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postPublishInteractionById.htm

You could schedule this within the script you are using to run these API calls